# Как в laravel route пустить все get запросы на один action?

Tags: laravel, laravel5, laravel-5.6, laravel5.4

Как в laravel route пустить все get запросы на один action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если для api роутов, в *routes/api.php*, например:

```
Route::get('/{any}', 'MyController@myAction')->where('any', '.*');
```

Если для web роутов, в *routes/web.php*, например:

```
Route::get('/{any}', 'MyController@myActio')->where('any', '^(?!api).*$'); // before the any was: ".*"
```

Выражение значит `.*` значит любой маршрут, а `^(?!api).*$` значит любые роуты но которые не начинаются api

Если бы вместо `^(?!api).*$` было тоже `.*`, то в api роутах не работало бы это:

```
Route::fallback(function() {
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Route not Found!'], 404);
});
```